# Maven - EJB plugin in parent pom

Tags: java, maven, maven-plugin, maven-3

I've just been asked to work on an existing Java EE web project.

The project contains a lot of modules, some EJB packaged in a EAR and a web part inside a WAR.

What is bothering me is that you actually need 1h30 to compile the whole stuff.
And I found this inside the parent POM betwen the plugin managment part :

```
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-ejb-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <ejbVersion>3.0</ejbVersion>
                <generateClient>true</generateClient>
                <clientIncludes>
                    <!-- Includes only service interface and business delegate. -->
                    <clientInclude>**/*Service.class</clientInclude>
                    <clientInclude>**/*Delegate.class</clientInclude>
                    <clientInclude>**/ejb/*EJBRemote.class</clientInclude>
                </clientIncludes>
                <archive>
                    <manifest>
                        <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                        <addDefaultImplementationEntries>true</addDefaultImplementationEntries>
                        <addDefaultSpecificationEntries>true</addDefaultSpecificationEntries>
                    </manifest>
                    <manifestEntries>
                        <Build-Time>${timestamp}</Build-Time>
                        <Implementation-URL>${project.url}</Implementation-URL>
                    </manifestEntries>
                </archive>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

Doesn't this means that every module is being "parsed" by the EJB plugin?
even non-ejb modules?

Thanks.

ps : the parent pom also have some dependancies that also are inside the modules' pom.

Comment: If this in the pluginManagement than this means that it is not "parsed" for every module. If there is an plugins block in the appropriate modules than it will be executed for the appropriate module.

Comment: Is the time you've given the whole time or is this really only the time for compiling? Or is it inclusive the tests etc. ? How many modules do you have? How many tests? Are the tests running in parallel?

Comment: this is the whole time, BUT I watched the console the entire time (working hard you see =D)

the only time consumoing operation are done by the mvane-compile-plugin.

it always block on "compiling XX sources files"

Comment: I have 10 modules, some EJB some regular and 1 dynamic web project.
I'm not doing any test myself.

With te -T4 option the compile time drops to 28 minutes (still too much if you ask me)

Comment: Which version of the maven-compiler-plugin do you use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I totally forgot this : I found the solution and then the project "only" needed 15 minutes to be compile.

The java version needed to be upgraded, from what I remember there is some kind of bug with maven and java 1.6 version xxxxx.

At the time upgrading to the lastest version of java 1.6 solved the problem (or it was 1.5 I don't remember).